# Add elements to search history?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

I have a model - Movies. 
and two controllers - first for search movie by title, second - for display result with poster, title and year.
Now i need to create some history search on my third controller 
(searchHistoryController - TableView) where displayed all movies, and when i tapped on cell with movie's title show movie info.
How I can build it? 
I tried create array in my model. And write resutl in it, but each time when i use search it rewrite array, not add new element. 
Maybe use realm
Need some help:)

**Movie.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage


protocol MovieDelegate {
    func updateMovieInfo()
}

class Movie {
   private let omdbUrl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?"
    var title: String?
    var filmYear: String?
    var poster: String?

   var delegete: MovieDelegate!

    var historyMovie = [Movie]()



    func getMovieInfo(title: String, completion: @escaping ()->()){
        let params = ["t": title]
        Alamofire.request(omdbUrl, method: .get, parameters: params).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON):
                let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
                let status = response["Response"] as! String
                if status == "True" {
                    self.title = (response["Title"] as! String)
                    self.filmYear = (response["Year"] as! String)
                    self.poster = (response["Year"] as! String)
                  //  self.delegete.updateMovieInfo()
                    completion()
                } else {
                    self.title = (response["Error"] as! String)
                    completion()
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print (error)

            }
        }

    }

}
```

**SearchVC**

```
import UIKit
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {
    var movie = Movie()
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func searchButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.movie.getMovieInfo(title: self.searchTextField.text!, completion: {
                 self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "movieInfo", sender: self)
            })
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let secondVC = segue.destination as! DetailInfoViewController
        secondVC.movieTitle = movie.title!


    }

}
```

**DetailVC**

```
class DetailInfoViewController: UIViewController, MovieDelegate {

    @IBAction func showHistory(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showHistory", sender: self)
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var posterImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var filmNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var filmYearLabel: UILabel!
    var movie = Movie()
    var movieTitle = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.movie.getMovieInfo(title: movieTitle ) {
            self.updateMovieInfo()
        }
        self.movie.delegete = self
    }

    func updateMovieInfo() {
        getPoster(link: movie.poster)
        filmNameLabel.text = movie.title
        filmYearLabel.text = movie.filmYear
    }

    func getPoster(link: String?) {
        if link != nil {
            guard let url = URL(string: link!) else { return }
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.posterImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    }
                }
            }        } else {
            self.posterImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Image")
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, movieHistory should not be part of your Movie class, but part of your SearchViewController class.
Second of all, unless you want to persist your data, you don't need Realm for this.

Just save the movies in SearchViewController into an array once the search button has been tapped and send it to your other view controller in the segue. Like so

```
@IBAction func searchButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.movie.getMovieInfo(title: self.searchTextField.text!, completion: {
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                movieHistory.append(movie)
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "movieInfo", sender: movieHistory)
            })
        }
    }
```

Also, modify prepare(for segue:...) like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let secondVC = segue.destination as! DetailInfoViewController
        secondVC.movieTitle = movie.title!
        secondVC.movieHistory = movieHistory
    }
```

In detailVC override prepare(for segue:...) as well and send movieHistory to searchHistoryController the same way it is done in the previous VC.